# How do i turn a text file into an array in python?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

my text file is just one column of data. the data is all floats. How can i turn this one column into an array in python. I know their must be a simple way of doing it i just can't figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you want an array *of floats*, considering you said your input data is all floats.

You can iterate over a file object to produce each line.

You can turn a string into a float by calling `float()`.

```
result = []
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = [float(line) for line in f]

print result
```

Results:

*myfile.txt*

```
1.234
4.456
7.999
```

*Output:*

```
[1.234, 4.456, 7.999]
```

If you want to get really crazy (and don't care exactly when the file will be closed), you can do this in one line:

```
result = map(float, open('myfile.txt'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mylist = open('myfile.txt').readlines()

print mylist
```